# How to create login part using Facebook in c# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm using ASP.NET c# mvc with entity framework tobuild a website. In there i have added facebook login part to the site. And here is my AuthConfig.cs file

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using TheFoody.Models;

namespace TheFoody.App_Start
{
    public static class AuthConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterAuth()
        {
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
                appId: "",
                appSecret: ""
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Here i have added the values for appId and appSecret. But when i'm running my app it will not show me the link to the facebook login.

I've prefered [enter link description here](http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/oauth-facebook-login-for-asp-net-mvc-website-with-example) and Other youtube videos. They have that facebook button in there login page. But for me it looks like this.

[image]

Do i need to add a button or it appears automatically? If i need to add that button then how should i set the URL for that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go thorough [MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

As per this you not need to add additional code, after adding code:

```
  app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
       appId: "000000000000000",
       appSecret: "000000000000000");
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to run the application.
Then, you will be able to see the login button for Facebook.

Comment: If you don't mind can you say whether this AuthConfig.cs file need to be auto generated when the project creating or can we create it manually?. Because i saw in some reference materials they uncommented the above lines from the AuthConfig.cs file. But in my case i have created it manually and add above code there.

Comment: Okay, So you are taking about `ConfigureAuth` method of `Startup` class. that will add automatically when you add `Microsoft.Owin`

Comment: Actually i didn't get understand what you said here? Can you simply say what i need to do?